# AttributeError: 'Backtest' object has no attribute 'data', Pandas, SMA crossover

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, algorithmic-trading

Trying to make this code work but I am not sure if I am passing the parent class correctly, also is the use of self.data proper? could there be a more concise way to code this...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import os
import pandas_datareader as pdr

start = pd.to_datetime("Jan 1st 2013")
end = pd.to_datetime("Dec 31st 2018")

class StockData:
    ticker = []
    def stock(self,symbol):
        self.ticker.clear()
        self.ticker.append(symbol)
        self.data= web.DataReader(self.ticker,"yahoo", start, end)

class Backtest(StockData):
    def prepare_indicators(self):
        self.data['SMA1'] = self.data[self.symbol].rolling(self.SMA1).mean()
        self.data['SMA2'] = self.data[self.symbol].rolling(self.SMA2).mean()
        self.data['SMA_1'] = self.data[self.symbol].rolling(self.SMA1).mean().shift(1)
        self.data['SMA_2'] = self.data[self.symbol].rolling(self.SMA2).mean().shift(1)
    def backtest_strategy(self, SMA1, SMA2):
        self.SMA1 = SMA1
        self.SMA2 = SMA2
        self.prepare_indicators()
        print(self.data)
        self.data['Signal'] = np.where((self.data['SMA1'] > self.data['SMA2']) & (self.data['SMA_1'] < self.data['SMA_2']), 1, 0)
        self.data['Signal'] = np.where((self.data['SMA1'] < self.data['SMA2']) & (self.data['SMA_1'] > self.data['SMA_2']), 0, self.data['Signal'])
        self.data['Sell'] = self.data.apply(lambda x : x['Adj Close'] if x['SMA1'] > x['SMA2'] and x['SMA_1'] < x['SMA_2'] else 0, axis=1)
        self.data['Buy'] = self.data.apply(lambda y : y['Adj Close'] if y['SMA1'] < y['SMA2'] and y['SMA_1'] > y['SMA_2'] else 0, axis=1)
        self.data['TP'] = self.data['Buy'] + self.data['Sell']
        self.data['TP'] = self.data['TP'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
        self.data['Position'] = self.data['Signal'].replace(to_replace=0, method= 'ffill')
        self.data['Buy & Hold Returns'] = np.log(self.data['Adj Close'] / self.data['Adj Close'].shift(1))
        self.data['Strategy Returns'] = self.data['Buy & Hold Returns'] * Self.data['Position'].shift(1)
        self.data[['Buy & Hold Returns', 'Strategy Returns']].cumsum().plot(grid=True, figsize=(9,5))
```

---

> > sma = Backtest()

---

> > sma.backtest_strategy(50,200)

AttributeError: 'Backtest' object has no attribute 'data'

Answer (score 0):

The pattern how to define variables in a classes is as follows:

```
class Xxxx:
    staticVar = ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.instanceVar = ...
```

So each variable used in a class should be defined:

- either as a **static** variable (not "owned" by any particular instance of
  this class), created in this class, outside any method,
- or as a **instance** variable (owned by particular instance), created by the
  constructor.

A class variable can also be defined in other method, within this class.

Your code contains a single place where *self.data* is assigned,
in *StockData.stock* method, but this method is **never** called.

Other places where you refer to *self.data* have the form of:

```
 self.data[...] =  self.data[...]...
```

so at this time, this variable must be created earlier.

One of possible solutions is to add a constructor (maybe to *StockData*)
and set this variable to whatever value you wish.

Or maybe you should call *stock* somewhere in your code?

Another concept is to:

- turn this function into a constructor (leaving *symbol* parameter),
- when you call *sma = Backtest()*, pass some value for this parameter.

But probably you should change *append* to *extend*. The reason is that
if you pass a string as *symbol*, it is actually also a list of chars,
so *ticker* will contain **individual chars**.
But if you change to *extend*, the whole string will be added as one
element.